# Updating Snowflake tables through MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a very "quick and easy" way to maintain Snowflake tables that I could handover to "End Users".
I personally use DBeaver but I don't want that sort of tool in an End User hands... (too open)

I have really enjoyed (still do) MS Access as a simple front-end to SQL Server.

Is MS Access a reasonable option for Snowflake?
I don't need anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can link MS Access to Snowflake. You can use ODBC DSN to provide connection parameters and connect over it. Connection parameters include Snowflake username, password , account URL and warehouse.

Comment: I just tried but I get an error "cannot define field more than once." on each table. According to comments on the web, it's due to our extensive use of underscore in our table and column names. I tried to create a view to switch this to CamelCase but then Snowflake does not allow inserting into a view... workarounds are getting too painful... :-(

Comment: I think that error is specific to Access, not Snowflake. I am not sure what you mean about inserting into a view as that seems like an entirely different question.  If your question is, can you connect Snowflake with Access, then yes, it is possible via ODBC.  If there's another question on what functionality is possible with Snowflake or if there's limitations of Access, feel free to post what specifically you are looking to accomplish (SQL statements, errors, whether it works in Snowflake but not Access, etc.) and we will try to help.

Comment: Yes, you are right in that error is specific to access but I think the answer to the question "Updating Snowflake tables through MS Access?" is "not really...".

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting, I think the answer to my question is "No" because Access imposes so many naming restrictions on the Snowflake table that it is not practical.

Unlike SQL Server where it is possible to update views as linked tables (subject to a few restrictions), Snowflake does not accept updating any view. Only tables. (I tried using a view to work around the columns naming restrictions).

Finally, an attempt to update a table with no underscore in either table name or column names (restrictions due to access) still resulted in an ODBC error "Streaming value for bind variable not supported"...

The point of using MS Access being that it's quick and easy, it's not really working in this case...